# Unable to fetch from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch from a MySQL Database using PHP and at the moment having no luck and I'm not sure why.

```
<?php 

include "base.php";

$CurrentID = 1;

$Message = mysql_query("SELECT Message FROM wall WHERE MessageID = 1");

$MessageFetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($Message);

echo $_MessageFetch['Message']

?>
```

Database:

[alt text http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/844/screenshot20100805at013.png](http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/844/screenshot20100805at013.png)

Comment: When echo $Message it returns Resource ID 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra underscore in:

```
$_MessageFetch
```

.

```
echo $_MessageFetch['Message']
```

should be

```
echo $MessageFetch['Message']
```